# Suppose $R$ is a relation on $X$. What does it mean if $R$ is both a partial order and an equivalence?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

Suppose $R$ is a relation on $X$. What does it mean if $R$ is both a partial order and an equivalence?

I couldn't think of anything else other than $\emptyset$, is this correct?

Comment: Did you roll a die when you chose the tags?

Comment: @ Asaf karagila I didn't. It's from my textbook on chapters that related to set. maybe I should have put relation there as well. don't you think?

Comment: I don't know. Perhaps you should have considered that many people have worked very hard on putting these small instructions on when to use a certain tag, when you hover the tag or when you have the option of choosing it. So... maybe read those before putting two irrelevant tags?

Comment: A well-ordering is a very specific kind of partial order, not relevant to this question. And "elementary-set-theory" is the more appropriate tag; "set-theory" is reserved for more advanced topics.

Comment: @ Noah Schweber thanks for telling me, guess everyone has their first time wetting their pants in bed, I will make sure this won't happen again.

Comment: But is it, though? I mean, each of the other five questions in your profile tagged under [tag:elementary-set-theory] had the [tag:set-theory] tag removed from them.

Comment: @ Asaf Karagila I really appreciate your generous pointing out of my mistakes, guess not very many people have the same passion as you do in helping people to grow to become better, you are a great champion! like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\emptyset$ *isn't* an equivalence relation (unless $X$ is empty), since it's not reflexive: any equivalence relation must contain at least the "diagonal set" $\{(x, x): x\in X\}$, this is exactly what reflexivity demands.

In fact, if we think about the diagonal set, it should quickly become clear that it's an example of an equivalence relation which is also a partial order! So we have one example.

Now, we want to figure out if there are any others. Here's the crucial point:

> Suppose $R$ is a partial order. Given $x$, how many $y$ can there be such that *both $xRy$ and* $yRx$ hold?

Once you answer this, you should - together with the fact that any equivalence relation contains the diagonal set - be able to figure out what all the appropriate relations are ...

Comment: 14 seconds... getting slow there, buddy? ;)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I quit coffee ... :P

Comment: @ Noah Schweber Thanks for your great answer, I got it very well.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between a partial order and an equivalence relation is that one is antisymmetric and the other is symmetric.

This means that if $x\mathrel{R}y$, then also $y\mathrel{R}x$ by symmetry; and therefore $x=y$ by antisymmetry.

Therefore $R$ can only be one thing.

(Also note that $R$ cannot be $\varnothing$, as long as $X$ is not empty, since both things require reflexivity, which ensures that $x\mathrel{R}x$ for all $x\in X$.)